# Electric igniter using 9V battery

Tags: batteries, resistors

I want to make a wire glow using a simple 9V battery. Will a simple resistor prevent this from being a short circuit and safety hazard? How do I decide which resistor to use?

The hazard I am afraid of is an exploding battery. The glowing wire is intentional, and not the hazard I am afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

A disposable cautery pen does just what you need. You can use a piece of nichrome wire 22 gauge or so made into a small loop. You may have to experiment to get the right length for the red glow.

Answer (score 0):

An incandescent lamp (like in a flashlight (torch)) will glow when connected to a 9 V battery.

For a bare wire in air, a PP3-type  V battery won't provide enough current to be dangerous; adding a resistor will cause the resistor to heat up.

Comment: That actual depends on the size of the wire - enough current can be delivered to get fine wire glowing red hot.

Comment: So I should safely be able to short a PP3-type V battery, without worrying about it exploding in my hand?

Comment: Not a lithium one, but the older Alkaline ones are probably OK; certainly for a couple of minutes. I would stop if it gets too hot to touch.

Answer (score 0):

A glowing wire is a safety hazard. To make it less hazardous, you need to figure out how to support the wire so it won't touch anything that will burn. You also need a pushbutton switch that has a spring, so that the switch is only closed as long as you press the button.

Use a 1.5 volt D cell. That will put out a high current without heating up too quickly. The low voltage will allow you to use a short piece of wire that doesn't have a very high resistance. You can use a special high-resistance wire material like nichrome, but something as simple as the spring out of a retractable ball-point pen will work. Find out how long the piece of wire should be by trial and error. Connect the hot wire to the battery with a fairly heavy piece of copper wire, lamp cord or heavier.

Comment: I want to light a cigarette with a glowing aluminum wire. What I am worried about is that the battery might explode or something, if I don't limit the current. I'll definitely try with a spring from a ball-point pen.

Comment: I don't think aluminum is a good choice. The resistivity is too low, the melting point is too low, and it would oxidize too easily. With a 1.5 V battery, the wire piece that you will heat can limit the current without additional resistance. With a 9 volt battery, you will waste energy in the resistor and may not be able to get the wire hot without too much stress on the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Your glowing wire needs to be the resistor.  If you put a resistor in series with a normal wire, you'll just get a cold wire and a hot resistor.